# C++ Input File from command line

Tags: c++

So I have a project that that requires me to doing something like:

```
./test < input.txt
```

But not all the time. The program can also be run as:

```
./test
```

with some different code between the two. I'm having trouble being able to differentiate between the two in code. For example, both have an argc value of 1.

What's the best way to tell whether or not there is an input file in the command line?

Comment: Programs can't tell the difference. Input redirection is handled transparently by the shell.

Comment: Usually if a program needs to operate differently, what it really cares about is whether standard input is a terminal or a file, not whether redirection was done on that command line. On Unix the `isatty()` function can be used.

Comment: What kind of difference are you supposed to make between the two?

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to detect the difference between `./test input.txt` and `./test`?

Comment: Perhaps you should edit the question and paste in more of the assignment text. Either this is much more complicated than your instructor likely intended or you have misinterpreted the instructions.

Comment: You should improve your question (by editing it) to explain your use case and the general context. Most of the time you should not make any difference.

Comment: You cannot, and you should not try. You most probably have misunderstood your assignment.

Answer (score 2):

There are **no general ways**, and it is *operating system specific*. I am focusing on Linux and POSIX systems. Notice that `test` is a poor name (colliding with [test(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html)...) and that `mytest < input.txt` stills gets its input from stdin since the [redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) is done by the [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) before starting your `mytest` program with [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).

The usual way to read from a file would be to give it as explicit argument: `mytest input.txt` (then test `argc`). I strongly recommend having such a convention. See also [getopt(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt_long.3.html), read about [program arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html).

On Linux (or POSIX), you might use [fstat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fstat.2.html) and/or [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) on `STDIN_FILENO` (i.e. 0) and even that is not be bullet proof, e.g. for [pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) or [here documents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

You  might even want to consider the case of batch invocation (i.e. `at` or `crontab` jobs) and background jobs.
For that you could also check the environment, see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html). Read also [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) on controlling terminals and sessions ([setsid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsid.2.html)) and [job control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix)). See also `/dev/tty` (so [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html), [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html), and the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)). BTW, you could also care about *stdout* or *stderr* being (or not) redirected.

I recommend being able to overcome such an autodetection with explicit program arguments, because it won't be perfect since there are corner cases (what about `mytest < /dev/stdin` and `mytest < /dev/tty` ? Do you consider these as redirections to be detected ?). There are [conventions and habits](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/307472/40065) about program arguments.

Few programs are doing such an autodetection, and those that do are providing a way, thru program arguments, to overcome it (for example, `ls --color` and `emacs -nw`).

Answer (score 0):

The `<` operators is used for input redirection. This just means that the file specified after `<` replaces `stdin` for that program.

The other method you have does not replace stdin, so the normal stdin file is read from.

In both cases you are still reading from stdin, <s>so no worries</s>, so you might want to double check what the actual requirements are.

Comment: But he says in the question that the program is supposed to do different things depending on which way it's used.